# Securing tensorflow-lite model

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm developing an Android app that will hold a tensorflow-lite model for offline inference.

I know that it is impossible to completely avoid someone stealing my model, but I would like to make a hard time for someone trying it.

I thought to keep my .tflite model inside the .apk but without the weights of the top layer. Then, at execution time I could download the weights of the last layer and load it in memory.

So, if someone try to steal my model he would get a useless model because it couldn't be used due to the missing weights of the last layer.

1. It is possible to generate a tflite model without the weights of the last layer?
2. Is it possible load those weights in a already loaded model in memory?

This is how I loading my .tflite model:

```java
    tflite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(), tfliteOptions);

    // loads tflite grapg from file
    private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = mAssetManager.openFd(chosen);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }
```

3. Are there other approaches to make my model safer? I really need to make inference locally.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about Keras models ( or any other model in TF ), we can easily remove the last layer and then convert it to a TF Lite model with `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter`. That should not be a problem.

> Now, in Python, get the last layer's weights and convert it to a nice JSON file. This JSON file could be hosted on cloud ( like Firebase Cloud Storage ) and can be downloaded by the app.

The weights could be parsed as an `array()` object. The actiavtions from the TF Lite model could be dot multiplied with the weights parsed from the JSON. Lastly, we apply an activation to provide predictions, which we need indeed!

> The model is so precisely trained that it could be rarely used for any other use case. So, I think we do not need to worry about that.

Also, it will be better if we use some cloud hosting platforms, which use requests and APIs instead of directly loading a raw model.

Comment: I dont see to glue together again those pieces in the android to do the inference. May you provide some code or link that might help ?